# ng-click is not working as expected

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-click

I have been trying to implement a mock up angular project.
I am using ng-click event to a button so when it is clicked it will open a edit modal that will show the respective name of the enterprise, and other details which I can edit, 
The problem is that I have to click more than two times open the modal, same problem occurs with the delete button too.
Can Anyone suggest me where I am going wrong?
My controller has the following function,

```js
function updateEnterprise(name) {
            $http.get(path + '/enterprise/' + name + '/find')
            .then(function success(response) {
                vm.oldEnterprise = response.data;
                console.log(vm.oldEnterprise);
                vm.name = vm.oldEnterprise.name;
                vm.email = vm.oldEnterprise.email;
                vm.sector = vm.oldEnterprise.sector;
            }, function error(response) {
                console.log('error');
            });
        }


        function editSubmit() {
            var name = vm.name;
            var email = vm.email;
            var sector = vm.sector;
            var req = {
                method: 'post',
                url: 'http://localhost:3000/enterprise/update',
                data: {
                    'name': name,
                    'email': email,
                    'sector': sector
                }
            };

            $http(req).then(function success(response) {
                vm.statuscode = response.status;
                vm.content = response.data;
                console.log(response.data);
            }, function error(response) {
                console.log('error');
                vm.statuscode = response.status;
            });
            $('#myModal').modal('hide');
            $window.location.reload();
        }
```

updateEnterprise is called in the following table element,

```
 <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary" 
         data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
     <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit" 
           ng-click="vm.updateEnterprise(enterprise.name)"> 
     </span>
 </button>
```

The editSubmit is called in the modal body,

```
 <form class="col-xs-12" ng-submit="vm.editSubmit()">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control form-design input-lg enable" ng-model="vm.name" placeholder="New Enterprise Name">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="email" class="form-control input-lg enable" ng-model="vm.email" placeholder="New Email Address">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group font-style form-style">
                    <label>Sector:</label>
                    <input type="radio" name="sector" value="Public" ng-model=vm.sector>Public
                    <input type="radio" name="sector" value="Private" ng-model=vm.sector>Private
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-block btn-lg font-style">Update</button>
                </div>
```

Comment: Change function updateEnterprise(name) into vm.updateEnterprise=function(name) and function editSubmit() into vm.editSubmit=function(name), Also can you provide us your whole controller ?

Comment: Try declaring your `function` inside scope using `$scope` like `$scope.updateEnterprise = function(name){....}` and `$scope.editSubmit = function(){....}`

Comment: I fixed it, It was a css issue I added ng-click to the span attribute instead of button element

Comment: please then answer your own question and accept your own answer :) so others with similar problem can see